# PXEBoot UEFI not downloading configuration files

Tags: debian, grub2, uefi, pxe

I setup dnsmasq (ver. 2.76 to support UEFI)
When the client starts the DHCP requests are made.
Proper file name is propagated to the client (via TFTP) but client only downloads this *grubx64.efi* file and nothing happens.
I presume the client should be requesting *grub.cfg-01-MAC*
After a while **only the grub2 shell appears** without pxe booting process.

Virtualbox/QEMU doesn't even send the DHCP requests and the whole process doesn't work (I followed [this to setup UEFI](http://blog.system76.com/post/139138591598/howto-qemu-w-ubuntu-xenial-host-uefi-guest))

1. Are my assumptions correct? After downloading grubx64.efi, should the client request grub.cfg-01-MAC?
2. Is it possible that my efi file is broken? (I've tried multiple efi files: redhat one, debian one, the stock one from the Foreman installator). What is wrong that it doesn't download config files and does nothing!?
3. Why virual env doesn't work at all?

Originally asked here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foreman-users/eBa5Nenw-Xw